# How to get Unique Device Id from a Jquery, HTML5 Mobile app

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I am building mobile apps for iOS, Android and Blackberry, Here's how I do this

1. I build an app using jQuery, HTML5.
2. Make a Zip file of that package.
3. Using http://build.phonegap.com I build that app created in jQuery, HTML5 and that phonegap interface provide me build package for every device i.e. iOS, Android and Blackberry.

So this way I just have to create one app and phonegap gives me that app's package for different devices every thing is good but now I am stuck in a problem, I want to identify each device on which my app is installed uniquely but of course solution have to be global I mean I should not write different code for different platforms and devices as far as possible and solution should be using only jQuery, HTML5.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`device.uuid`, gives you something like that but as the docs says

> Not a reliable value

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.uuid

Maybe you can store a GUID, Pseudo-Random Number or something generated at install time... (i really mean, the first time you run the app)

**UPDATE**:
JS Pseudo-Random Number Implementation:
[Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

Comment: It's "Not a reliable value" because on IOS it will give you an application guid that's per phone/application.  I think the device.uuid could still be a valid approach.  Has anyone tried using the device.uuid for device tracking?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the device object provided by cordova? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device

You should be able to determine what platform your app is running on at runtime.

Comment: cordova provides UUID which is not unique, see this http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-get-mobile-imei-code and I have tested it too.