# how to get Mobile UUID CODE using j query, javascript or mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to get the Mobile Universal Unique Identifier( UUID) code using MVC, J query or java script.
I tried to get the code but no luck so any body can help me out to get it..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Unique Device Id from a Jquery, HTML5 Mobile app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478319/how-to-get-unique-device-id-from-a-jquery-html5-mobile-app)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this **isn't possible.**

Available information over the navigator (means JavaScript, jQuery, etc.):

- Geo-location
- IP address
- Browser software
- Exit location
- Entrance location
- Screen Size
- Allowed Cookies
- Allowed Java
- Mobile or Desktop
- Language
- Perhaps some more...